# ¿como permito que mi aplicación, acceda a firebase realtime, en modo bloqueado?

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase, firebase-auth, realtime-database

Tengo una app que esta autenticando con firebase con email y contraseña.
Uso tambien firebase realtime, pero no se como funcionan las reglas.
¿Como puedo poner, que solo mis usuarios de firebase puedas tener acceso a lectura?.

En mi app, uso este codigo para leer datos:

```
database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){}
```

**Edit:**
Esta es mi base de datos Firebase

[image: FB]

Lo que quiero conseguir es que los `Users`,  con su identificador, puedan leer los datos `Peliculas` y `Series`

He probado estas regla pero no funcion

```
"rules": {
    "Peliculas": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
```

@A. Cedano, no se si me he explicado

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no entiendes de las reglas? ¿Qué reglas has intentando aplicar? ¿Qué pruebas has hecho? ¿Qué comportamiento tienen o qué errores estás recibiendo?

Answer (score 0):

Ya esta solucionado, lo logre con

```
    {
  "rules": {
    "Peliculas": {
        ".read": "auth != null"
      },
    "Series": {
        ".read": "auth != null"
      },
    "Users": {
        ".write": "true"
      }
    }
    
}
```

Con estas reglas pueden leer solos los usuarios identificados, y escribir solo en `Users` para registrarse.